# Using $(this) & event in named handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
function showPost(event){
    event.preventDefault();
$(this).parent('article').animate({width:'100%'}, 'slow');
}
```

I am attempting to use it like so:

```
$('.article-header').click(function(event){showPost(event);});
```

When I use it in the above manner, the event property is passed just fine, however `$(this)` doesn't work within the function. If I attempt to include `this` as a parameter in the `.click` method, it returns an error claiming `this` is undefined. I have even gone so far as to set `var ths = $(this);` to no avail.

Please, what is the proper way to make this function happen?

Comment: The event is passed automagically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the function directly:

```
$('.article-header').click(showPost);
```

You're loosing `this` because you're calling the function "naked", with no object receiver. You could do this too (but don't because there's no point here):

```
$('.article-header').click(function(event) { showPost.call(this, event); });
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I had tried this, but mistakenly changed `showPost(event)` to just `showPost()`. A mistake I really shouldn't have made.